# Solving $x^3+24x^2+5x-13 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, cubics

I have been doing some mathematics and I have come across this question that I need to somehow solve to move onto the next questions. I'm currently undertaking an abstract algebra unit with this questions as part of an assignment:

$x^3+24x^2+5x-13 = 0$

Can anyone help and solve with a step by step method so that I have a stronger understanding rather than just receiving the final answer?

$x_1 = 0.63204...$
$x_2 = -23.76661...$
$x_3 = -0.86543...$

Thanks! :)

Comment: There's a closed form, see [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).  Usually, though, people stuck to numerical methods.

Comment: You want what?  Numerical solution, such as Newton's method?  Exact formula (this is the "casus irreducibilis", where--despite the solutions being real--you have to use either complex numbers or trigonometric functions for the formula)?

Comment: OH! That actually helped out heaps! Found a piece of information that I was missing out before and applied it to my work and it seems to have fixed my issues. (reply to lulu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to follow the steps described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) to have exact and nice-looking formulae ?

For your equation
$$p=-187 \qquad q=971 \qquad \implies \qquad\Delta=700105$$ so three real roots.

Now apply the trigonometric method to get
$$x_k=-8+2 \sqrt{\frac{187}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{2 k\pi  }{3}+\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{2913 }{374}\sqrt{\frac{3}{187}}\right)\right)\qquad (k=0,1,2)$$ which give your numbers.

Comment: (+1) This is similar to [Solving $x^3 + 12x^2 + 8x − 7 = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3683660), which I answered in much the same way.

Comment: For sure ! I like very much the trigonometric method and the hyperbolic one except when I compute. There so many accuracy issues. I spent amost 40 years with cubic equations (thermodynamics) and, independently of the CPU time, we found that to be almost sure of the results at least quadruple precision was required (for Cardano).

Comment: Beside the fact that even if the roots are real, Cardano often requires using complex numbers.